# Word for "having characteristics of the beach?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

> The city had a tropical, [...] feeling to it.

I thought of the word *beachy* but I worry people will confuse it with the other similar-sounding word.

Comment: What attributes of the beach are you looking for? There are many. I'm afraid any word meaning simply *beach-like" is going to miss your point. A desert island beach evokes different images compared to a beach resort.

Comment: Canis seems to have the fundamental point down here: context matters.  Are you trying to connote relaxed, airy, aloof, humid, etc feeling... which brings one to the analysis of "feeling" -- are you telling the feeling or showing?  In non-fiction, telling will work, sometimes in fiction telling will work, oftentimes, though, showing is the more effective means of expression.

Comment: what about relaxed, resort-like, holiday, ... or similar adjectives you would indeed use for "beach"

Comment: First, it is important to know if it has a beach-like feel to it (because it really has beach) or (although it has no beach). Which is the present case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Beach-like"?

> The city had a tropical, beach-like feel to it

Answer (score 5):

"Littoral" describes something of the part of the sea close to the shore and has a more professional sound.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you might go with "seaside" which carries many of the connotations, but might be too broad for your needs.